# What's the difference between capitalized and lowercase versions of Keras.losses and Keras.metrics?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

While I was constructing a simple Sequential ANN and selecting parameters for the `model.compile` method, I observed that `Keras.metrics` and `Keras.losses` contain capitalized as well as lowercase versions, for example `tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy` versus `tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy`. I was wondering what the difference is between those versions and which one is more suitable to be used in `model.compile` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy` is a Class so you get an object and you can pass it over to `model.compile`. Since it is an object it can have state between the calls.

However `tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy` is a function and it is stateless. Both perform the same operation but their usage is different.